# How to use Apriori Algorithm in Dask Dataframe?

Tags: dask, dask-ml

I want to use Apriori Algorithm for my dataset to find the associated products. But the data I have has 14 million records, so I can't use it directly with MLEXTEND. I have loaded the data into Dask data frame.

Could anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: Please include some code that you tried and problems that you faced. Ideally a minimal, verifiable example.

Comment: I didn't get the code for Dask yet!